# CheckBox Family Issues

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrc4N/4/) Working here with checkboxes.

My problem is: when I check indiviually all the child checkboxes the parent is not checked and it is not fading out.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".pc-box").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest("li").find(".cc-box").prop("checked", true);
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        }  
    });
    $(".cc-box").click(function() {
        if (!this.checked)
            $(this).closest("ul").prev().fadeIn().find(".pc-box").prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you get your answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `parents()` instead of `parent()`. `parent()` is used to target immediate parent while `parents('#selector')` is used to target the parent in the chain unless the selector is found

use this code:

```
$(".pc-box").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parents("li").find(".cc-box").prop("checked", true);
            $(this).parents('li').fadeOut();
        }  
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrc4N/7/)**